# Compile and install pure Kernel on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, linux-kernel, compiling

I'm trying to compile and install the kernel-4.9.8 sources from https://kernel.org on Debian 8 (jessie).

I'm following this procedure:

- `make defconfig`
- `make menuconfig`
- `make`

I managed to compile the sources succesfully, but I can't install the kernel,
I've tried with both `sudo make install` and sudo `dkms autoinstall -k 4.9.8`, but they seems to require `linux-headers-4.9.8` and I can't find it the Debian repositories.

Comment: I recommend reviewing the [Debian Linux Kernel Handbook](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/). And you can find official 4.9 kernel packages in the jessie backports repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `make-kpkg` instead. When run from a kernel source tree it'll compile a kernel and build a full set of debian packages using that source and config -- `linux-image`, `linux-headers`, `linux-doc`, all as per your version specified.

It's part of the `kernel-package` package, so what you want to do is:

1. `sudo apt-get install  kernel-package`
2. Edit `/etc/kernel-img.conf` and `/etc/kernel-kpg.conf` to match your preferences
3. `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd linux-image`
4. Sit back, get some tea. The above process will take a while.

It will generate a `linux-image-(version)` deb package one level up, which you can then install with dpkg and will handle things like calling your bootloader's update to add the new kernel automatically. This will *significantly* ease your difficulties.

At the end of this process, you will have a Linux kernel that has the *exact* capabilities you told it to have, and none of the capabilities that you didn't tell it to have.

Consider that last sentence a polite warning.

Comment: Yeah, this works, but what's up with the good old way?

Comment: You mean the way that doesn't handle the bootloader, doesn't check dependencies and will blithely overwrite files without checking? The "good old way" you can't manage to get to work? There's a reason most sensible people stopped using it.